# How do you say "mild vomiting due to a Stomach Bug"?

Tags: translation

My son has picked up a stomach bug at his kindergarten.  I'm going to the pharmacy and I want to tell the German pharmacist that he is having mild vomiting from a simple stomach bug and I want some medicine to help settle his tummy.

I saw there were 2 words for vomiting:  *Das Erbrechen* and *die Übelkeit*. Which is appropriate or is there a better way to say what I want?

Comment: To make a "best" answer possible we may want to move the "Stomach Bug" part to a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Übelkeit** is just a general feeling of unwell. It can, but does not have to be connected with vomiting.

**Erbrechen** is the actual vomiting.

However, I would suggest using a verbalised form and prefer *übergeben* instead of *erbrechen*:

> Ihm (Meinem Sohn) ist übel. Er hat sich (ein paar Mal) übergeben.

This connects both: He is feeling unwell and has vomited.

I'm not sure how to say *mild vomiting*, because vomiting never seemed mild to me … My best guess is to say *a few times*.

Comment: Just to note... the term "leichtes Erbrechen" (mild vomiting) does exist. But it would sound odd to my ears to say "Mein Sohn hat leichtes Erbrechen". https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22leichtes+erbrechen%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Emanuel Yes, it sounds more like something a physician would diagnose than what a parent would say to the pharmacist.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tell them is:

> Mein Sohn hat im Kindergarten Bauchschmerzen bekommen, und fühlt sich etwas übel und muss sich auch übergeben.

Answer (score 0):

*Stomach bug* würde ich als *Magenverstimmung* übersetzen. In jedem Fall würde ich aber, wie in den anderen Antworten schon gesagt, auch die Sypmtome (Übelkeit und Erbrechen) erwähnen.